# why does my angularjs $http.get request with params not return filtered results?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, get, angular-filters

I apologise if this is a stupid question. I am running a $http.get() request in my client controller to retrieve objects including a particular id. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance!

```
$http
    .get('api/offers', {
        params: {
            taskId: vm.task._id
        }
     })
     .success(function (data,status) {
          vm.task.offers = data;
          console.log(data);
//          if (vm.task.offers.taskId === vm.task._id) {
//              console.log(vm.task.offers);
//          }
     });
```

However, the request is returning all data in the mongodb document.

I have tried filtering in my html page but also not working.

```
<ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="offer in vm.task.offers | filter: { offer.taskId : vm.task._id } : true">
```

Get request is getting `/api/offers?taskId=570999f043131bb7ade86185` in my browser network resources, again this end point returns all entries in my document, rater than filtered by the taskId.

Comment: How are you accessing the taskId on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `ng-repeat` filtering you made a mistake, have it like below.

```
ng-repeat="offer in vm.task.offers | filter: { taskId : vm.task._id } : true"
```

Comment: thanks so much for your very fast response. I will try this now and let you know how I get on!

Comment: this worked perfectly. I can accept as an answer in 6 mins. thanks so much!

Comment: @loulala glad to help you. Thanks :)